# understanding selectors memoization with reselect and objects

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit, reselect

There is an article on the Redux website about selector memoization with the Reselect library, where they provide next example:

```js
const state = {
  a: {
    first: 5
  },
  b: 10
}

const selectA = state => state.a
const selectB = state => state.b

const selectA1 = createSelector([selectA], a => a.first)

const selectResult = createSelector([selectA1, selectB], (a1, b) => {
  console.log('Output selector running')
  return a1 + b
})

const result = selectResult(state)
// Log: "Output selector running"
console.log(result)
// 15

const secondResult = selectResult(state)
// No log output
console.log(secondResult)
// 15
```

Overall this example is clear, except for the `selectA1` selector.
Redux docs stated that

> When you call the selector, Reselect will run your input selectors with all of the arguments you gave, and looks at the returned values. If any of the results are === different than before, it will re-run the output selector, and pass in those results as the arguments.

So, if we provide `state.a`, which is object, as an input selector for `selectA1`, it will fail `===` check and run `a => a.first` every time, right? Or have I misunderstood something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, if we provide `state.a`, which is object, as an input selector for
> `selectA1`, it will fail `===` check and run `a => a.first` every time,
> right?

No, an object reference will ***always*** be strictly equal to itself.

The `selectA` selector function returns `state.a` which is a reference to an object with value `{ first: 5 }`. `state.a` will continue to ***always*** be a reference to ***this*** object until an action is dispatched to update `state.a` to then be a reference to a ***new*** object with a value, *then* the `selectA1` selector function will recompute its output value.

I hope this snippet helps illustrate object reference equality.

```js
const state = {
  a: { first: 5 },
};

const selectA = state => state.a;

// same reference, true
console.log(selectA(state) === state.a);

// same "value", but false because different reference
console.log({ first: 5 } === state.a);
```